# Hardy $H^2$ space - equivalence of definitions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, hardy-spaces

Can you please explain the equivalence of the following definitions of the Hardy $H^2$ space? The Hardy $H^2$ space is the class of holomorphic functions $f$ on the open unit disk satisfying:

First definition:

$$
{\displaystyle \sup _{0<r<1}\left({\frac {1}{2\pi }}\int _{0}^{2\pi }\left|f\left(re^{i\theta }\right)\right|^{2}\;\mathrm {d} \theta \right)^{\frac {1}{2}}<\infty }
$$

Second definition:

$$
f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nz^n, \quad \sum_{n=0}^\infty |c_n|^2 < \infty
$$

Comment: Use the orthogonality of the exponentials.

Comment: This is classic maths. See the first chapter of Shapiro's _Composition Operators and Classical Function Theory_ for a lovely and quick explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n z^n$ is holomorphic on the open unit disk, then the series converges absolutely and uniformly on any closed subspace of the open disk. For a fixed $0 \le r < 1$, the function $f(re^{i\theta})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n r^n e^{in\theta}$ is an absolutely convergent Fourier series with coefficients $c_nr^n$ for $n \ge 0$ (the Fourier coefficients for negative $n$ are all $0$.) By Parseval's theorem for the Fourier series, the $L^2$ norm of the function is the sum of squares of the Fourier coefficients
$$
      \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta 
          = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|c_n|^2r^{2n}.
$$
The above is finite for any fixed $0 < r < 1$ because the series converges uniformly on any circle of radius $0 < r < 1$. By the Monotone Convergence Theorem applied to the sum, the following holds, whether the expressions are finite or infinite:
$$
        \sup_{0 < r < 1} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta = \lim_{r\uparrow 1}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}|c_n|^2.
$$
So $f=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}c_n z^n$ is in $H^2$ iff $\sum_{n}|c_n|^2 < \infty$. And, if $f\in H^2$, $\|f\|^2_{H^2}$ is equal to the above.

Comment: thank you very much for a perfectly clear proof!

Comment: @Konstantin : You're welcome.

Comment: Sorry but why is the series a Fourier series? Could you recall the definition? I have looked here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series but I can't find a more or less simple definition.

Comment: @user770533 : Sorry for the very late comment. I just happened to notice this for another reason. For a fixed $0 \le r < 1$, the series is the Fourier series of $f(re^{i\theta})$ for a fixed $r$ because the series expansion for this is an absolutely convergent series with coefficients $c_nr^n$.

Comment: Do you mean for every fixed $0 \leq r \lt 1$ the infinite series $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} c_n r^n e^{i n \theta}$ is the Fourier series of $f$ on the circle of radius $r$ on which the infinite series converges uniformly and absolutely by Hadamard's theorem?

Comment: When you are using MCT I think you are working on the following setting $:$ For each $0 \leq r < 1$ consider a sequence $f_r$ defined by $f_r(n) = |c_n|^2 r^{2n},\ n \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}.$ Then the infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} |c_n|^2r^{2n}$ is nothing but the integral of $f_r$ on $\mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ with respect to the counting measure. Since $f_r(n)\ \big\uparrow\ |c_n|^2$ for every $n \geq 0$ as $r\ \big\uparrow\ 1$ by MCT it follows that  $\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{\infty} |c_n|^2r^{2n}\ \big\uparrow\ \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} |c_n|^2$ as $r\ \big\uparrow\ 1.$ Am I right?

Comment: @AkiroKurosawa : Your next to the last comment is about as clear as anyone could make it. Your last comment seems to be equally clearly written. I don't see anything wrong with what you are saying.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts$:$ I just tried to make things clear for my own sake. Your answer is itself self explanatory in full generality. Please don't mind. I tried to explain in more detail in my way of understanding. I don't have any other intention. Pardon me please.